# Avoid last loop iteration

Tags: c, loops, while-loop

I built a simple function that, given an integer, returns every smaller square. Es:

```
input: 80
output:
1
4
9
:
64
```

So I tried with a `while` and a `do..while` loop:

```
int main(){
    int x;
    int y = 0;
    int z = 0;
    while(x < 1){
            printf("Insert an integer number greater than 0\n");
            scanf("%d", &x);
    }                                     #approach with do..while
    while(z <= x){                        #do{
            y += 1;                           
            z = y * y;
                printf("%d\n", z);
    }                                     #}while(z < x)
return 0;
}
```

My output goes up to:

```
    input: 80
    output:
    1
    4
    :
    81
```

How can I make the loop avoid the last iteration, since the condition `z <= x` will be true only then, actually producing a non valid output?

Comment: "interaction" should be "iteration"!

Comment: And `while(x < 1)` with uninitialized `x` is a source of troubles.

Comment: `while((y += 1, z = y * y) <= x) printf("%d\n", z);`

Comment: @barakmanos why does `x < 1` represent a source of troubles?

Comment: "interation" should be "iteration"!

Comment: Because you are not initializing `x` prior to this expression.

Comment: your `x` variable is not initialized which means that it contains a garbage value and doing `while(x < 1)` will cause trouble because of garbage value.. You need to initilialize it to `0` and also increment it in your `while loop`

Comment: @Yousaf: OP doesn't need to "increment it in your while loop", because that's not the purpose of the program.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much for the explanation. I was not aware of garbage values. Time to fill my gap :)

Comment: BTW, don't you feel that something in "a positive integer number greater than 0" is a little redundant? (hint: either the "positive" or the "greater than 0").

Comment: May I have a feedback about the downvote, in order to avoid them? I thought the question was quite correctly composed.

Comment: @barakmanos yoa are right, it is redundant, but, how you surely suspected, I am a student practicing, and at this level is not uncommon providing more information than necessary.

Comment: Many of the down-votes are a bad custom of this website. More precisely - those that come without any comment explaining them. They are irritating, no doubt, and in many cases are made by smart@$$es who think they're smart. The site regulation should probably force an anonymous comment alongside every down-vote. Until then, there's nothing much that you can do about it. I will compensate you with a +1...

Comment: @barakmanos I think nonconstructive criticisms are not that useful, in terms of didactic progression. On the other side, I agree that many come here in order to find the solution for an immediate problem, rather than opportunities to increase knowledge. In the and, I agree with your proposal. Anyway, thanks for your advices and support. Time to learn about garbage today :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just say

```
int x = 0;
int z = 1;
int y = 1;
```

at the beginning, and

```
printf("%d\n", z);
y += 1;                           
z = y * y;
```

in the loop

EDIT: problem is the order of your statement. You print first and check later.

Complete answer is below:

```
int main(){
    int x = 0;
    int y = 1;
    int z = 1;

    while(x < 1){
            printf("Insert a positive integer number greater than 0\n");
            scanf("%d", &x);
    }                                     //approach with do..while
    while(z <= x){                        //do{
            printf("%d\n", z); 
            y += 1;                           
            z = y * y;
    }                                     //}while(z < x)
return 0;
}
```

Comment: x gets a random value so %50 of times it works correctly i think :D but saying x = 0 is the key

Comment: Aww that was a trivial problem, sometimes I still forget to consider the most important elements. Thanks!